# Google Analytics view filter pattern isn't matching root directory

Tags: regex, google-analytics

I'm trying to create a Google Analytics view Filter Pattern with the following settings:

Filter Type: Custom 
Include Filter Field: Request URI

The filter should inlude:

```
/
/ (token1 token2) <-- edge case that needs to be matched
/subdir1
/subdir1/subsubdir
/subdir2
/subdir2/subsubdir
```

The filter should not inlude:

```
/admin
/admin.php
/admin/admin.php
```

The approach I figured would work was to have the following:

root directory pattern OR subdirectories pattern

To match the subdirectories I successfully tested:
^/(subdir1|subdir2).*$

I can't figure out how to match the root directory.

I've tried:

```
^/$
^\/$
^/?$
```

The final pattern would be something like

^/$|^/(subdir1|subdir2).*$

**How do I match just the root directory?**

Answer (score 0):

Try Regex: `^(?:\/(?:(?:subdir1|subdir2))?(?:\/.*)*)?$`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/W5lmTy/4)

Explanation:

```
Non-capturing group (?:\/(?:(?:subdir1|subdir2))?(?:\/.*)*)?
? Quantifier — Matches between zero and one times, --> this will match the root directory
\/ matches the character / literally (case sensitive)
    Non-capturing group (?:(?:subdir1|subdir2))?
    ? Quantifier — Matches between zero and one times
        Non-capturing group (?:subdir1|subdir2)
            1st Alternative subdir1
            2nd Alternative subdir2
Non-capturing group (?:\/.*)* --> this will match the / and characters that follow subdir1 or subdir2
* Quantifier — Matches between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
\/ matches the character / literally (case sensitive)
.* matches any character
```

Comment: The root directory still isn't matched (in google analytics)

Comment: could you provide an example of the root directory, that you are trying to match?

Comment: It's the root directory of the redirect uri, so I guess it's just /, it's when the uri is something like example.com (with no directories in the path)

Comment: Try Regex: `^(\/(?:subdir1|subdir2)(?:\/.*)*)?$`. [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/W5lmTy/2)

Comment: There is an edge case that needs to be handled, I've updated the question. Is there an easy modification to your regex that would also match the two words in brackets? thks

Comment: Matt I found a way to remove the edge case. Your regex works great. I'm having trouble making sense of how your regex works. Could you add a few words of explanation? (I tried reading the demo explanation but it's confusing me even more)

Comment: @vy218, I have updated my answer with the explanation. I've slightly modified the regex to handle `\` after the root. if you could comment how you handled the edge case, I could add it to the answer.

Comment: I removed the edge case from my code so it doesn't exist anymore, no need to handle it.

Comment: In the regex why is there a non-capture group inside a non-capture group? (?:(?:subdir1|subdir2))?

Comment: that is to handle `www.example.com/` . In the Demo link, try removing the outer non capture group, we can see that the second line `/` is not matched. `?` for the outer non capture group will make subdir1 or subdir2 optional.

Comment: I was able to simplify your regex by removing all the unnecessary non-capture groups. See [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/p7eTh1/1). All the non-capture groups really confused the heck out of me. Anyways I now know how to match the root directory. Don't forget about the actual question! Thanks

Comment: Please note that this regex will match `/subdir1abc` and 
`/subdir2def` [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/p7eTh1/2). A simplified version `^\/((subdir1|subdir2)(\/\w+)*)?$` [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/W5lmTy/5). I ended up adding the additional groups to handle both `www.example.com` and `www.example.com/`